# JavaScript : this.$emit('closeRequest') is not create any event in vue dev tool

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am following a tutorial and they doing a project. everything is perfect and i was doing well. but i face an error. i have a component (Home.vue) and inside component there have a button. if user click the button then a modal will open (using BULMA scss framework and there is no js). when button is clicked then another component (Add.vue) will appear where actual modal code is writed. i pass a property Home.vue to Add.vue via `<Add></Add>` Component. this property value is tell modal will active  or not.

here is home.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<nav class="panel column is-offset-2 is-8">
    <p class="panel-heading">
        VueJs Phonebook
        <button class="button is-link is-outlined" @click="openAdd">
            Add New
        </button>
    </p>

</nav>

<Add :openmodal='addActive'></Add>

</div>
</template>

<script>
let Add = require('./Add.vue')
export default {
    components:{Add},
    data(){
        return{
            addActive:''
        }
    },

    methods:{
        openAdd(){
            this.addActive = 'is-active';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

i am successfully get the property in Add.vue but modal has cancle and close button. i use to write a method called `close`. if button is clicked the  `this.$emit('closeRequest');` should make a event in vue dev tool. but it do not create any event if cancle or close button was clicked.

here is Add.vue file

```
<template>
 <div class="modal" :class="openmodal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
         <button class="delete" aria-label="close" @click='close'> 
</button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
        <!-- Content ... -->
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
        <button class="button" @click='close'>Cancel</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    props:['openmodal'],
    methods:{
        close(){
            this.$emit('closeRequest');
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <template>
<div>
<nav class="panel column is-offset-2 is-8">
    <p class="panel-heading">
        VueJs Phonebook
        <button class="button is-link is-outlined" @click="openAdd">
            Add New
        </button>
    </p>

</nav>

<Add :openmodal='addActive' @closeRequest='closeAdd'></Add>

</div>
</template>

<script>
let Add = require('./Add.vue')
export default {
    components:{Add},
    data(){
        return{
            addActive:''
        }
    },

    methods:{
        openAdd(){
            this.addActive = 'is-active';
        },
        closeAdd(){
            this.addActive = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```